# Where to ask about website security?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site where I can ask about website security?

I'm looking for a site that can help my job, currently as a Web Tester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), but as with any SE site, make sure to read the [FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) first.

Obviously, if IT Security doesn't cover the specific question you have, we can probably recommend another site if you give us just a little bit more detail. :)

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: I think IT Security can handle it for now. If you have another suggestion I'm very appreciated.